# Snapcraft removed all my data without --purge

Tags: snap, brave

I was told that I can re-install an app safely using `snap remove brave` and then `snap install brave` without losing the app data, so long as you don't add `--purge`.

So this is what I did. During the remove step there was a message: "backing up data for #112".
I then re-installed, ran the app. Yeah, all data is gone, complete blank slate...

My question is: Is there ANY other location where the data might have been backed-up to other than `/snap/<app>/` where I can restore it from?

EDIT: Just discovered that the data was saved:

```
~ » snap saved                                                                                                     andre@andre-office
Set  Snap   Age    Version  Rev  Size    Notes
31   brave  51.5m  1.24.82  112  1.72GB  auto
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, turns out that the snapshot was indeed saved it just didn't automatically restore it when I re-installed. The way that snapcraft makes these backups is detailed here: https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapshots

Looking at my saved snapshots showed that it was saved:

```
~ » snap saved                                                                                                     andre@andre-office
Set  Snap   Age    Version  Rev  Size    Notes
31   brave  51.5m  1.24.82  112  1.72GB  auto
```

So I just had to run, `sudo snap restore 31` to get it all back.

Answer (score 0):

Today i installed fsuae snap, play around with it a bit and wanted to compare the launch speed with deb package (it mas much slower than native deb). It appeared, that snap moved all FSUAE data (configurations, kickstarts, whdload key) to snap folder. Fortunately, i noticed this before deleting the snap, because i would have lost all the application data irretrievably.