# Unable to launch some snap packages

Tags: snap

I'm unable to launch *some* snap packages after my system crashed a couple hours ago. Everything was perfectly fine before my system crashed. Started happening when I managed to get my system working again.

Discord for example gives me this error:

```
ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-28-1804 content interface.
```

The docker daemon also won't start:

```
$ snap logs docker
2021-05-10T09:34:02Z systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
2021-05-10T09:34:02Z systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
2021-05-10T09:34:02Z docker.dockerd[9114]: failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: listen unix /var/run/docker.sock: bind: operation not permitted
2021-05-10T09:34:02Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2021-05-10T09:34:02Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2021-05-10T09:34:03Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
2021-05-10T09:34:03Z systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
2021-05-10T09:34:03Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
2021-05-10T09:34:03Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2021-05-10T09:34:03Z systemd[1]: Failed to start Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
```

Brave browser also didn't start, at first I thought I just need to re-install, which worked, BUT without saving my brave data, so the browser now doesn't know any of my pages, bookmarks, settings or anything. (I did NOT use `--purge` when removing). See: [Snapcraft removed all my data without --purge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337302/snapcraft-removed-all-my-data-without-purge) for that issue

EDIT: The issue with brave data have been resolved, it did save that data, just didn't auto-restore the data when I reinstalled. (See the link above for details).

Some information:

```
~ » snap version                                                                                              64 ↵ andre@andre-office
snap    2.49.2
snapd   2.49.2
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.4.0-72-generic
```

Comment: Can you add output from `snap version`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix done

Comment: I found this online which might be of some help: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/error-not-connected-to-the-gnome-3-28-1804-content-interface/23342/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was resolved by following the process of removing and re-installing the snap as mentioned above.

This did however result in me thinking that the snap data was deleted and not backed up correctly. Turns out that it is backed up but you have to manually restore the backed-up data. [See this question for more details on that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337302/snapcraft-removed-all-my-data-without-purge)